# form values not passing through action url in php

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post, select

I have a simple form made in PHP, I am trying to pass the select value in the page mentioned in the action URL,

```
<form action="filtertable.php" method="post">
    <select class="form-select" name="filtercategory" aria-label="Default select example"
        onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option selected>Select Category</option>
        <option value="<?php echo $roww["c_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $roww["cname"]; ?></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

when the user selects on any select box it will go to the page filtertable.php, and from there am trying to get the selected value like this:

```
<?php

$filtercategory=$_POST['filtercategory'];
```

However it doesn't work, can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here, thanks in advance

Comment: From what I can see and test, this should work. There might be something else in your code, which is not in your question, causing this problem.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this is only the code, just some select statment and while loop to get the values from database i trimmed to make it simple here

Comment: What actually doesn't work? Is the page not changing? Or the `$_POST['filtercategory']` is empty?

Comment: the page is being taken to filtertable.php correctly, but from there am not getting $_POST['filtercategory'], its empty

Comment: Did you already put them in `<?php` formatted code? And does the PHP server is running?

Comment: @You yes , https://jsfiddle.net/x4a1bmw0/1/ this is my filtertable.php code

Comment: That's a lot of code. Anyway, the first thing I would do is check the [console panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) for any error message.

Comment: Then check in the developer tools whether `$_POST` is indeed empty as you say. I doubt it is. And then I would add [PHP error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display), if you haven't already. Basically the standard debugging steps you would take in a situation like this.

Comment: From the linked code: When the page loads `$filtercategory=$_POST['filtercategory'];` this will cause an error as the page will be loaded using GET ( line #37)

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i didnt really understand

Comment: You have your code that _shows_ the form, and the code that is supposed to process the submitted data, in the same file here. When you first navigate to this script, either by putting the link into your browser address bar, or by clicking a link that leads to it - that will cause a _GET_ request. No form has been submitted at this point, no POST data will exist. Yet you are trying to access `$_POST['filtercategory']` anyway; of course it will be empty at this point.